IntelliJ - microservice setup with Python
I have the following folder structure:

ProjectName

main

components

component_one (package)
component_two (package)
component_three (package)


libraries

core

common (package)









Each component is a Python package managed by Poetry. The core package contains shared libraries. Currently, IntelliJ with Python plugin does not recognize the shared common module (It's built and packaged with Poetry). The content root path is set to the ProjectName folder.
How do I get IntelliJ to recognize the shared package? I'm starting the modules from within the components folder (IntelliJ recognizes ProjectName.main.libraries.core.common, but It is imported as common.something as that's how It's packaged with Poetry)

You can add ProjectName/main/libraries/core to PYTHONPATH via File | Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs:


It's still referencing it through main.components... etc
